# Clicking suspend turns the screen black for a moment and then takes me to login screen

Tags: 20.04, suspend, login-screen

Suspend was using fine, but for some reason unknown to me it has stopped working properly and takes me back to the login screen. I suspect that something is instantly causing the computer to wake up after suspend. How can I see what's happening?

Thanks

Comment: Within 3 minutes of trying to suspend, `sudo journalctl  --since="-5 minutes"` in a terminal will show lots of log messages, some of which will be about suspend/resume.

Comment: Thanks, I did that but I cannot locate where exactly the problem is.